# increment float32 by smallest possible amount (using numpy currently)

Tags: python, numpy

Trying to increment a single-precision floating point number by the smallest possible amount. I see there is a nextafter function, but I can't get that to work for single precision numbers. Any suggestions?

Comment: how is it not working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems to work fine:

```
>>> x = np.float32(1.)
>>> y = np.nextafter(x, np.float32(2.))
>>> y
1.0000001
>>> type(y)
numpy.float32
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the float32 as the second parameter. Awesome.